# How to step into Android OS's source code when debugging?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, operating-system

Is there a way to step into system calls when debugging an Android app on eclipse?

Maybe a similar way to how source code of a JAR library can be pointed to in eclipse and debugging would be possible on the library code. The difference is that Android's system libraries are not compiled with the Android app so I'm not sure how and where to tell eclipse: "here is Android's source code. Find your way in it.".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In your Android SDK Manager, check and download "Sources for SDK" for the target platform you are working on.
2. When you get an error in Eclipse and the debugging perspective pops up, click on "attach source" and choose "external folder". Navigate to ur android-sdk/sources/ and select the folder corresponding to the platform.

Is this what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this.

http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

http://www.mkyong.com/android/attach-android-source-code-to-eclipse-ide/

Comment: I would refrain from posting links in your answer as links could be broken in the future. Instead, quote your source(s) and abbreviate your answer.